# SQL Server Express 2008 connection string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I am trying to configure my connection using SQL Server Express 2008.

Can anyone help me please. My server name is as follows: `test\expressql2008` and my database is `TestDatabase`

My connectionstring is :

```
<add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" 
     value="Server=localhost\EXPRESSQL2008;Database=TestMyproject;User=Me;Pwd=test;" />
```

It seems that the connections isn't working and I get the error:

> NHibernate.ADOException : cannot open connection

Comment: Can you provide the full connection string?

Comment: <add key="hibernate.connection.connection_string" value="Server=.\SQLEXPRESS\EXPRESSQL2008;Database=TestMyproject;User=Me;Pwd=test;" />

Comment: The error messge is:  cannot open connection ----> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: You say your database is `TestDatabase`, in your connection string, you have `TimeKeeper` and in your comment you mention `TestMyProject` - so which is it now???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's all connectionstrings needed

http://connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
<add name="SD_ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=[SQLEXPRESS NAME];Initial Catalog=TestDatabase;User ID=[USERNAME];Password=[PASSWORD]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

string con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SD_ConnectionString"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more detail about this error there could be number of reasons

1- Please check ASP.NET user has access to your database if you are using trusted connection.
2- It could be better if you create a SQL USER and assign it permission of DBOWNER to your database and with your connection use that user information.

Answer (score 0):

con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);

in web.config